# Why is it saying syntax error for no reason

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I am a couple steps away from creating my first game but the syntax error incoming up for no reason and if there are any more errors instead of that please tell me!

I have tried everything but I can't make it work

I have read everything on this website and can't find anything that makes it work maybe its a more complex mistake I suppose so please help me I am struggling really badly

```
import pygame
import time
import random
pygame.init()

display_width = 800
display_height = 600

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)

red = (200,0,0)
green = (0,200,0)

bright_red = (255,0,0)
bright_green = (0,255,0)

block_color = (53,115,255)

carImg_width = 73
carImg_height = 62

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('A bit Racey')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

carImg = Actor("car.png")


def things_dodged(count):
    font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 25)
    text = font.render("Dodged: "+ str(count), True, black)
    gameDisplay.blit(text,(0,0))

def things(thingx, thingy, thingw, thingh, color):
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, color, [thingx, thingy, thingw, thingh])

def car(x,y):
    pygame.Surface(Actor), (int width , int height)

def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, black)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

def message_display(text):
    largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',115)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects(text, largeText)
    TextRect.center = ((display_width/2),(display_height/2))
    gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

    pygame.display.update()

    time.sleep(2)

    game_loop()



def crash():
    message_display('You Crashed')

def button(msg,x,y,w,h,ic,ac,action=None):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    print(click)
    if x+w > mouse[0] > x and y+h > mouse [1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ac, (x,y,w,h))
        if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
            action()
            #if action =="play":
                #game_loop()
            #elif action == "quit":
                #pygame.quit()
                #quit()

    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ic, (x,y,w,h))



        smallText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',20)
        TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects(msg, smallText)
        TextRect.center = ( (x+w/2),(y+h/2) )
        gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)




def game_intro():

    intro = True

    while intro:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            print(event)
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',115)
        TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("A bit Racey", largeText)
        TextRect.center = ((display_width/2),(display_height/2))
        gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

        button("Go!",150,450,100,50,green,bright_green,game_loop)
        button("Quit",550,450,100,50,red,bright_red,"Quit")




        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)



def game_loop():
    x = (display_width * 0.45)
    y = (display_height * 0.8)

    x_change = 0

    thing_startx = random.randrange(0, display_width)
    thing_starty = -600
    thing_speed = 4
    thing_width = 100
    thing_height = 100

    thingCount = 1

    dodged = 0

    gameExit = False

    while not gameExit:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    x_change = -5
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change = 5

            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change = 0

        x += x_change
        gameDisplay.fill(white)

        things(thing_startx, thing_starty, thing_width, thing_height, block_color)



        thing_starty += thing_speed
        car(x,y)
        things_dodged(dodged)

        if x > display_width - car_width or x < 0:
            crash()

        if thing_starty > display_height:
            thing_starty = 0 - thing_height
            thing_startx = random.randrange(0,display_width)
            dodged += 1
            thing_speed += 1
            thing_width += (dodged * 1.2)

        if y < thing_starty+thing_height:
            print('y crossover')

            if x > thing_startx and x < thing_startx + thing_width or x+car_width > thing_startx and x + car_width < thing_startx+thing_width:
                print('x crossover')
                crash()

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)

game_intro()
game_loop()
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: You didn't post the error traceback. What is your error? Your title is not good for future searches. Syntax errors have a reason. Welcome to SO anyway.

Comment: You can edit your question to enhance it.

Comment: What is `Actor`?  And what do you think you're doing here: `pygame.Surface(Actor), (int width , int height)`?

Answer (score 0):

There were 4 errors,

1. You used  car_width instead of carImg_width in many places.
2. Your car() function was wrong
3. `carImg = Actor("car.png")` - Where is this function defined?
4. you forgot to use blit() to display your car image

A working version of your game

```
import pygame
    import time
    import random
    pygame.init()

    display_width = 800
    display_height = 600

    black = (0,0,0)
    white = (255,255,255)

    red = (200,0,0)
    green = (0,200,0)

    bright_red = (255,0,0)
    bright_green = (0,255,0)

    block_color = (53,115,255)

    carImg_width = 73
    carImg_height = 62

    gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
    pygame.display.set_caption('A bit Racey')
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    carImg = "car.png"


    def things_dodged(count):
        font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 25)
        text = font.render("Dodged: "+ str(count), True, black)
        gameDisplay.blit(text,(0,0))

    def things(thingx, thingy, thingw, thingh, color):
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, color, [thingx, thingy, thingw, thingh])

    def car():
        #return pygame.Surface((int(carImg_width) ,int(carImg_height)),0, carImg )
            return pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(carImg).convert(), (carImg_width, carImg_height))

    def text_objects(text, font):
        textSurface = font.render(text, True, black)
        return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

    def message_display(text):
        largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',115)
        TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects(text, largeText)
        TextRect.center = ((display_width/2),(display_height/2))
        gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

        pygame.display.update()

        time.sleep(2)

        game_loop()



    def crash():
        message_display('You Crashed')

    def button(msg,x,y,w,h,ic,ac,action=None):
        mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
        print(click)
        if x+w > mouse[0] > x and y+h > mouse [1] > y:
            pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ac, (x,y,w,h))
            if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
                action()
                #if action =="play":
                    #game_loop()
                #elif action == "quit":
                    #pygame.quit()
                    #quit()

        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ic, (x,y,w,h))



            smallText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',20)
            TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects(msg, smallText)
            TextRect.center = ( (x+w/2),(y+h/2) )
            gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)




    def game_intro():

        intro = True

        while intro:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                print(event)
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    quit()

            gameDisplay.fill(white)
            largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',115)
            TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("A bit Racey", largeText)
            TextRect.center = ((display_width/2),(display_height/2))
            gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

            button("Go!",150,450,100,50,green,bright_green,game_loop)
            button("Quit",550,450,100,50,red,bright_red,"Quit")




            pygame.display.update()
            clock.tick(15)



    def game_loop():
        x = (display_width * 0.45)
        y = (display_height * 0.8)

        x_change = 0

        thing_startx = random.randrange(0, display_width)
        thing_starty = -600
        thing_speed = 4
        thing_width = 100
        thing_height = 100

        thingCount = 1

        dodged = 0

        gameExit = False

        while not gameExit:

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    quit()

                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                        x_change = -5
                    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                        x_change = 5

                if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                        x_change = 0

            x += x_change
            gameDisplay.fill(white)

            things(thing_startx, thing_starty, thing_width, thing_height, block_color)



            thing_starty += thing_speed

            gameDisplay.blit(car(), ( x,y))
            #car(x,y)
            things_dodged(dodged)

            if x > display_width - carImg_width or x < 0:
                crash()

            if thing_starty > display_height:
                thing_starty = 0 - thing_height
                thing_startx = random.randrange(0,display_width)
                dodged += 1
                thing_speed += 1
                thing_width += (dodged * 1.2)

            if y < thing_starty+thing_height:
                print('y crossover')

                if x > thing_startx and x < thing_startx + thing_width or x+carImg_width > thing_startx and x + carImg_width < thing_startx+thing_width:
                    print('x crossover')
                    crash()

            pygame.display.update()
            clock.tick(60)

    game_intro()
    game_loop()
    pygame.quit()
    quit()
```

You car game screenshot:

[image]